# Is there a way I can create an either OR assertion using Pester test framework?

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, testing, assertion, pester

For example if I wanted to assert the value should be Value1 or Value2 (either is acceptable):

```
   It 'Value must match Value1 or Value2' {
         $params.value | Should -be "Value1" || "Value2"
    }`
```

This is invalid syntax - is there a way to do this with Pester?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [`-BeIn` assertion](https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/usage/assertions#bein):

```
if 'Value must match Value1 or Value 2' {
    $params.Value |Should -BeIn @('Value1','Value2')
}
```